# Rugged method equivalent to Grit's Repository#status

Tags: ruby, libgit2, rugged

Is there a method in Rugged (v0.19.0) equivalent to Grit's `Repository#status`?

I've found a `Repository#status` in Rugged too but it does not contain the info* I'm searching.

*Which staged files have additions and which new files were introduced in the Repository.

Answer (score 1):

You should use rugged from the dev branch, the 0.19 release is pretty old. The newer version of rugged/libgit2 epose more information.

When you call `Repository#status`, it returns al list of name+status pairs, which should have what you're asking for. What information is missing from there?

Comment: `Repository#status` requires a block. I wrote something like this `dummy = []; @repo.status { |s| dummy << s.inspect }` and I only got some filenames.

Comment: It gives you a name+status pair, if you took the second arg, you would be able to use it, `@repo.status { |name, status| puts name; puts status}`